# Smart search for Mysql on php in mamp

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table containing about lots of names of songs.
I want to create smart search, so that i can find specific song from name.
it should return then smart search result like google does.
(not as perfect as google)
I need spell mistake avoidance and ranking according to relevance.

is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: This is going to get closed. Still, you should look up `FULLTEXT` search.

Comment: i tried full text 

but it does not full fill my requirements

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a very broad question, to find a solution you should try to seperate the problems. A question about [spelling errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200935/best-way-to-deal-with-misspellings-in-a-mysql-fulltext-search) in mysql exists already.