# MySQL fulltext search can't find single misspellings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query on fulltext that seems to work with a misspellings if I'm using 2 words but it doesn't if I'm using just one word

I have a table with fullname field

And in the table "Nile Rodgers","Bam Rogers","Catherine Wyn Rogers","Nigel Rogers"

my query

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE MATCH (fullname) AGAINST ('myquerytext' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

if I search for "Rodgers" I  found "Nile Rodgers"

if I search for "Rogers" I  found "Bam Rogers","Catherine Wyn Rogers","Nigel Rogers" BUT NOT "Nile Rodgers"

if I search "Nile Rogers" I fond "Nile Rodgers","Bam Rogers","Catherine Wyn Rogers","Nigel Rogers"

Is it possible to adjust the tolerance?

Comment: My guess would be that `'Nile Rogers'` returns all the records, not because MySQL is handling alternate spellings, but because all the records match one of those 2 tokens. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200935/best-way-to-deal-with-misspellings-in-a-mysql-fulltext-search. If you want to handle alternate spellings/misspellings in MySQL, you can do something like create a SOUNDEX index. If switching RDBMSs is an option, Postgres has built-in support for word n-grams, which you can use to compare a word to its misspelled equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that it searches EITHER *Nile* OR *Rogers*, and so the results you get are logical.

If you want ALL the words and not ANY of them, use **BOOLEAN MODE** and add a `+` in front of each word :

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE MATCH (fullname) AGAINST ('+Nile +Rogers' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

> **12.9.2 Boolean Full-Text Searches**
>
> In implementing this feature, MySQL uses what is sometimes referred to
>   as implied Boolean logic, in which
>
> • + stands for AND
>
> • - stands for NOT
>
> • [no operator] implies OR

[Offcial doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)