# mysql ngrams indexing example

Tags: mysql, levenshtein-distance

As I have read in many parts, ngram indexing can improve word searches.
In this old post it says that it could be adapted for mysql but it does not say how: [levenshtein alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835098/levenshtein-alternative)

Can anyone put some example as you can use this technique in mysql?

Can use this technique to improve the performance of the levenshtein function for mysql?.

My need is to find approximate text (like levenshtein)

In mi tests I  used levenshtein() and levenshtein_ratio() functions from:
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=552

```
SELECT *, levenshtein_ratio('stacoverflou',words_column) AS ratio 
FROM my_table 
ORDER BY ratio DESC
```

That improve performance (Supposing not misspelled first letter)

```
SELECT *, levenshtein_ratio('stacoverflou',words_column) AS ratio 
FROM my_table 
WHERE words_column LIKE 's%'
ORDER BY ratio DESC
```

Also I found this php library for building ngrams:
https://gist.github.com/Xeoncross/5366393

But I have no idea how to use these ngrams in mysql

Answer (score 1):

**I have finally made an algorithm myself:**

**Generate ngrams algorithm:**

1. I build a *words* table with 3 columns: *ngrams* (fulltext), *word* (UNIQUE), *lang*
2. I used Bigrams() function to make ngrams for each word
3. I added a char padding to each ngram to skip the full text index minimum word length ex: '**abcd**' should be '**ab bc cd**' but with padding it look like '**abxx bcxx cdxx**'

**Search algorithm:**

4. I take the client written words as correct and use them to search in the real table 
   with mysql fulltext search query using **AGAINST('+word_1 +word_2 +word_n' IN BOOLEAN MODE)**
5. if the score (ranking) > 0 Mission accomplished and ngrams not used (show result to client)
6. If the score (ranking) = 0 (maybe misspelled words) then use ngrams words table to retrieve correct words

**Retrieve correct words from ngrams algorithm:**

7. For each word generate ngrams and preform a fulltext search query using **AGAINST('abxx bcxx cdxx' IN BOOLEAN MODE)** FROM *words* table (where we have the ngrams column) and retrieve the correct word. Note that here no (+) prefix to ngrams
8. Rebuild the search like as step 4
9. If score > 0 Mission accomplished -> show results -> END
10. If score still 0 then make another query but this time without (+) +word prefix and IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE -> show results -> END

Step 2 code:

```
// original from : https://gist.github.com/Xeoncross/5366393
// modified for working also with unicode characters

function Bigrams($word){
    $ngrams = array();
    $len = mb_strlen($word);
    for($i=0;$i+1<$len;$i++){
      $ngram = mb_substr($word, $i, 2);
        while(mb_strlen($ngram) < 4){
            $ngram .= "x";
        }
        $ngrams[$i]=$ngram;       
    }
    return implode(" ",$ngrams);
}
```

Step 4 code:

```
SELECT  my_column,
( MATCH(my_full_text_column ) 
    AGAINST('+word_1 +word_2 +word_n' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) AS score LIMIT 10
```

Step 7 code:

```
$word = "stacoverflou"; // Intentionally misspelled
$actual_word_ngrams = Bigrams();
//that return
//stxx taxx acxx coxx ovxx vexx erxx rfxx flxx loxx ouxx

SELECT  word,
( MATCH( ngrams ) 
    AGAINST('$actual_word_ngrams' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) AS score LIMIT 1
```

That return stackoverflow an can be used with ohers words (if many) to much more accurate search  like as step 4

END